# parallelize data manipulation using starmap

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

How can I parallelize the data manipulation without actually passing in the dataset?

"my_fun" takes a subset df columns, and perform some calculation.
I want to parallelize "my_fun" because the df contains many columns and my_func needs to be applied to many subsets of the df.
The plan is to use pool.starmap.

The pool.starmap requires the inputs of my_func stores in a list, and each element of the list will be fed into my_func in parallel during the execution. My dilemma is that df is a very big dataset, to prepare the input for starmap, I have to store the df to the list for many times and this depletes the memory.

```
def my_fun(col1, col2, new_col_name, df):
    return (new_col_name, df[col1] + df[col2])
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [10, 20, 30], [100, 200, 300]])
in_list = [(1,0,10,df), (2,0,20, df), (1,2,12,df)]

pool = Pool(4)
res = pool.starmap(my_fun, in_list)
```

Any suggestion to optimize above code, so that I don't have to store df to the "in_list" for n times where n is the times my_func will be called during the parallel execution?

Comment: `import functools; my_fun_parallel = functools.partial(pool.starmap, my_fun)`, though you should use `pool` in a context manager to cleanup the workers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should understand that you're storing N *references to the same DataFrame*, not N separate copies of it. So, there's technically nothing wrong with what you're doing.

I imagine `my_fun` is a dummy function for the sake of providing a MWE, but you should try to vectorize this operation without `multiprocessing`, if possible.

But to answer your question, I would curry `df.pipe` using `functools.partial`, so you end up calling the same function with different arguments.

```
def my_fun(df, col1, col2, new_col_name):  # note the argument order.
    return (new_col_name, df[col1] + df[col2])

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [10, 20, 30], [100, 200, 300]])
in_list = [(1,0,10), (2,0,20), (1,2,12)] # note `df` is gone from the argument list.
```

```
from functools import partial
pool = Pool(4)
res = pool.starmap(partial(df.pipe, my_fun), in_list)
```